# WordPress. Why pagination doesnt work with permalinks like /%postname% but works with default URLs?

Tags: wordpress, function, pagination, http-status-code-404

I have Custom Post Type.
Permalinks looks like /%postname%

My CPT function:

```
function cpt_lyrics() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'Lyrics', 'Post Type General Name', 'Lyrics' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'Lyrics', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'Lyrics' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Lyrics:', 'Lyrics' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'View Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'Lyrics' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'Update Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'Search Lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'Not found', 'Lyrics' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'Lyrics' ),
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'lyrics', 'Lyrics' ),
    'description'         => __( 'Lyrics Name', 'Lyrics' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', ),
    'taxonomies'          => array( 'bands', 'albums' ),
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 7,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'lyrics', $args );
}
```

Pagination function works, but it displays links like this: domain.com/page/2 and I get an error 404. 
But the pages are available at url like: domain.com/?page=2.
Why this happening?

Comment: Have you changed your permalink structure in the admin?

Comment: yes, in the admin panel, not .htaccess

Comment: Can you post the query from your loop?

Comment: of course,

`<?php if ( get_query_var('paged') )
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
elseif ( get_query_var('page') )
$paged = get_query_var('page');
else $paged = 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'lyrics', 'posts_per_page' => 12, 'paged' => $paged ));
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>`

Comment: Not too sure about that query. Try 
`if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

query_posts('posts_per_page=12&post_type=lyrics&paged=' . $paged);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it will be usefull for somebody... Add  this to functions.php:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) { 
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
$taxonomies = array ('YOUR_TAXONOMY');
    if(is_tax($taxonomies) || is_home())  {         
        $query->set ('post_type', 'YOUR_POST_TYPE');
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the paged query above your loop to make the pagination work for Custom Post Types I believe.

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged); 
?>
```

or

```
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); } 
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); } 
else { $paged = 1; }  
query_posts('posts_per_page=12&post_type=lyrics&paged=' . $paged);
```

Comment: Still does not work :\
May be rewrite urls with .htaccess or somethnig else?
I broke my head is why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

u can also used pagination plugion for the same.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/
or 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smart-pagination/
such as many more plugion..

Comment: Pagination is a fairly simple thing and I wouldn't suggest using a plugin for it

Comment: @Amit Lokulwar, I had a problem. not AdamHughes)
And, yes, it solved - see the latest answer